# How can i change the default error message for extention of the jquery's validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can i change the default error message of the jquery validation?

here is my html form:

```
<form id="form_detail_file3" action="{$form_action}" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="file" class="form-label">Inserisci il documento:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" name="fileToUpload"
                        id="fileToUpload">
                </div>
</form>
```

And JS:

```
$("#form_detail_file3").validate({
    rules: {
        fileToUpload: {
            required: true,
            extension: "jpg|jpeg|png|ico|bmp"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        fileToUpload: {
            required: "Please upload file.",
            extension: "Please upload file in these format only (jpg, jpeg, png, ico, bmp)."
        }   
    }
});
```

The code is working and i get require message when there is no file to upload ,however if the extention that provided is not mached it show this default message "Please enter a value with a valid mimetype.".

Comment: Please do not tag-spam.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if extension is not matched it shows "*Please enter a value with a valid mimetype.*"

Mimetype has nothing to do with file extension, therefore this **cannot** be the default message from the `extension` rule.

`"enter valid mimetype"` is the default error message from the `accept` rule, which validates mimetype, and that you have declared inline with your HTML markup here:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" name="fileToUpload" ....
```

This plugin is easier to use and understand when you declare all rules using one consistent method, rather than mixing inline HTML5 rules with your jQuery `.validate()` `rules`.

*The jQuery Validate plugin automatically converts various inline declarations into rules, such as HTML5 and certain class names.*

Example:  Inline `required="required"` or `class="required"` will do the same thing as `required: true` inside `rules` option of  `.validate()`.